# Cannot connect to database phppgadmin

Tags: php, database, phppgadmin

I cannot connect to the database. I already have phppgadmin and made a new database and table already. In my php file i encoded:

```
<?php
 $conn = pgconnect ("host = localhost dbname = sign_in         user = postgre password = 123456");
 if (!$conn){
   Echo "ERROR";
   }
?>
```

What should i do?

Comment: Its `pg_connect()` instead of `pgconnect()`

Comment: Check your error logs. Without a proper error, we're just guessing in the dark. You can try removing the spaces around the equal signs, eg `host=localhost dbname=signin...`

Comment: Nothing happened :(

Comment: I just solved it. I used the database under superuser instead